# How to copy & paste values and no format?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried `ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`.

```vb
Sub CopyCoverage()
    
    Dim x As Worksheet, y As Worksheet, LastRow
    
    Set x = Sheets("1SalesAnalysis")
    Set y = Sheets("Basics")
    
    LastRow = x.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    
    x.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    x.Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    x.Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    x.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    
    x.Range("E2:E" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    x.Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    x.Range("G2:G" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    x.Range("H2:H" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    
    x.Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    x.Range("J2:J" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    x.Range("K2:K" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    x.Range("L2:L" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    
    x.Range("O2:O" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "EA").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    x.Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "EI").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    x.Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "EB").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    
    x.Range("R2:R" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "EJ").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    x.Range("S2:S" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "EC").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    x.Range("T2:T" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "EK").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Pastevalues works for me. Show what you copy and the result. Or is the destination already formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the mapping rules in an array so you can reuse the same code for each column.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyCoverage()

    Dim wsX As Worksheet, wsY As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowX As Long, msg As String
    Dim rngX As Range, rngY As Range
    
    Set wsX = Sheets("1SalesAnalysis")
    Set wsY = Sheets("Basics")
    LastRowX = wsX.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    
    Dim map, ar, i As Integer
    map = Split("A=>E,B=>F,C=>G,D=>L,E=>M,F=>P,G=>Q,H=>R,I=>S,J=>T,K=>V,L=>W," & _
                "O=>EA,P=>EI,Q=>EB,R=>EJ,S=>EC,T=>EK", ",")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 0 To UBound(map)
        ar = Split(map(i), "=>")
        msg = msg & vbLf & ar(0) & " to " & ar(1)

        Set rngX = wsX.Range(ar(0) & "2:" & ar(0) & LastRowX)
        Set rngY = wsY.Cells(Rows.Count, ar(1)).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        rngY.Resize(rngX.Rows.Count).Value2 = rngX.Value2
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Copied " & msg, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: many many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way to avoid formatting not being copied/pasted is by not copying/pasting in the first place: you can simply do:

```
Destination_Range.Value = Source_Range.Value
```

Like this, only the value gets copied", but the formatting is not involved.

More information can be found in [this reference question about this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: but isnt the problem that i cant add .value to equation on the right? Because .value does not refer to a Range x.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Cells.Value = y.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Cells.Value

Comment: @Sven: I believe you'll need a `For Each` loop to copy all the values in your range.

Answer (score 0):

Those one-line 'copy-pastes' already finishes the task of copy-paste, so the ActiveCell.PasteSpecial at the bottom part of your code doesn't do anything.

There are several ways to do it but I will stick to the pattern of your code:

```
Sub CopyCoverage()
    
    Dim x           As Worksheet
    Dim y           As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow     As Long
    
    Set x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ans")

    LastRow = x.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False '~turn off the 'animation' to speed up a bit
    
    'The logic will be, copy-paste, copy-paste
    x.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy
    y.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    x.Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Copy
    y.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    'and so and so forth
    'Just continue with this pattern
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False '~end line
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True '~turn on the 'animation' again
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @ChaosPH but it submits me an error message ..it expects an intorduction end